# Gatsby + ThemeProvider StyledComponents has empty theme

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I am trying out Gatsby for the first time.  I setup my local dev env as I normally would without Gatsby, with a `<ThemeProvider />` wrapping the app from the root component.  It works great...until I try to run the command to make my app ready for production and serving `gatsby build`.  Then I get the error:

> WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'blue1' of undefined

After more reading, i am told to use the `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js` files with the `wrapRootElement()` API.  This now fails locally with the same error as when I tried to run the production build script above.

Why are my ThemeProviderProps empty still? I shouldn't have to wrap every component in Layout.

---

- package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.6",
    "gatsby": "^2.17.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.15",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.1.11",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-inlinesvg": "^1.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-helmet": "^5.0.14",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.25.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.25.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-tslint": "0.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.15",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.4",
    "tslint-react": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
```

---

Then the files to be ready by the `gatsby-config`:

- gatsby-ssr.js
- gatsby-browser.js

```
import { wrapRootElement as wrap } from "./root-wrapper";

export const wrapRootElement = wrap;
```

---

- gatbsy-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
    `gatsby-plugin-tslint`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`
  ]
};
```

---

- root-wrapper.js

```
export const wrapRootElement: FC<Props> = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Global />
      <Layout>{element}</Layout>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

---

- src/components/Layout.tsx

```
    const Layout: FC = ({ children }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <Helmet>
            ...
          </Helmet>
          <>{children}</>
        </>
      );
    };
```

---

- src/pages/index.tsx

```
export default (props: any) => <Home  />;
```

So when I put a debugger in the `Global` or `Home` components, theme is an empty obj `{}`.

What is happening for local development to make theme empty?

Comment: I'm also having this issue :'(